# Hide/Show specific content and save as localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, bootstrap-switch

I'm looking to use a bootstrap switch to [toggle](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/events.html) specific content to be hidden and shown, depending on whether it's checked or not. And I want to save the status of this checkbox in localstorage. I'm new to javascript and can't figure it out. I would appreciate any help that can be given...

[The jsfiddle is self-explanatory](https://jsfiddle.net/j9knzuh1/1/v). I'll paste the code here as well. Thank you kindly!

```
<div class="well text-center">
  <h1>Today's Games</h1>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="spoiler-checkbox" data-size="mini" data-on-color="danger">
  <br />
  <label for="checkbox">Spoiler-Free</label>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="Game1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="status" colspan="3" id="timeleft">3:31 3rd Quarter</th>
        <th class="status" colspan="3" id="starttime">7:30pm EST</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="team" colspan="2">Bulls</td>
        <td class="score" colspan="1">59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="team" colspan="2">Bucks</td>
        <td class="score" colspan="1">65</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
#timeleft {
    color:red;
}

#starttime {
    display:none;
}

.team {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```
$("[name='spoiler-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

---

**Update**:

K, with help from multiple sources, I have it working very well. Not the cleanest code, but doing exactly what I want it to.

http://jsfiddle.net/j9knzuh1/28/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can perfectly save and retrieve the state using localStorage with set and get methods. Just have to put a listener on `switchChange.bootstrapSwitch` and sotore the value on `localStorage` each time it is changed, and then do a simple validation every time the page is loaded to see if there is any value stored on the `localStorage` .

Note that values are stored as string, so, they should be converted back to its type, in this case boolean.
Here is your updated full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9knzuh1/24/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


//Set the listener to store data on localstorage whenever event switch is fired
    $("[name='spoiler-checkbox']").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
        if (localStorage)
        localStorage.setItem("ckbspoiler", state); //ckbspoiler is just the name you want
    });



// retrieve the localstorage value for ckbspoiler and set the last saved status if any
var lastState = null;
if (localStorage)
    lastState = (localStorage.getItem("ckbspoiler")  === "true"); //Notice we are using this to convert it to its natural type: boolean

//If there was a lastState saved, then update the checkbox status        
if(lastState != null)  $("[name='spoiler-checkbox']").prop('checked', lastState);


$("[name='spoiler-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();




 });
```

Comment: Thanks gabriel, this is a great start...  what about hiding and showing the specific classes/id... i'm not sure how that plays into this code? thank you again

Comment: What do you mean?...you mean the jQuery selector?..yes you can point to whatever element in any of the many ways: name, id, class, etc: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Ok, I have it hiding/showing the content I need upon the first switch, but I can't figure out how to make it go back to how it was upon the switchback... any help much appreciated. thank you very much. i'm quite new to this http://jsfiddle.net/j9knzuh1/25/